# How to render image on a full map in R

Tags: r, plot

I have pressure values on a set of points (given latitude and longitude values). I am plotting them in R using the following code:

```
data("wrld_simpl")
lon = dat$X - 180
lat = dat$Y
phi = dat$phi[,,1]
#quartz(width=11, height=4)
plot.new()
image(lon, rev(lat), phi, xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude")
title(main="Phi")
plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE)
```

This is the result:

[image]

I want the image to be rendered on the full map and not a truncated version. Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: This is unclear. What is truncated? The world map?

Comment: yes "plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE)" plots the full map.

Comment: There are `xlim` and `ylim` arguments in function `image`. Use them.

Comment: got it: xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-90,90). Thanks!